# What type of contractor do I call to build a custom pool equipment enclosure that attaches to my fence?

Tags: wood, woodworking, pool, aluminum

My pool equipment is right next to the fence line and is a horrendous site.
It is also quite loud.

I am looking for the **TYPE** of specialist/contractor/company that I should be looking into to come build a custom pool enclosure for me.

**Would it be someone who build fences or a pool company or a carpenter or something else?**

I'm afraid of the first person I call just telling me they can do it and then the enclosure is to small to do pool pump maintenance or too small and the pool pump gets extremely hot.

Answer (score 1):

Would figure a pool company will have or knows someone that knows how to build pool equipment enclosures.

They don't want their equipment being in the wrong enclosure.

Ask neighbours/friends for recommendations instead of just going with the first one in the phone book.

Comment: Social media *shudder* can actually be your friend in this instance, too. Asking for recommendations of either pool companies or fence builders from your circle of "friends" is likely to get at least a few decent recommendations that the OP can then vet for suitability.

Comment: @FreeMan   Social media needs too many filters. Nyquil chicken anyone, suppose to be tasty.

Comment: "*shudder*" and "vet for suitability" would be the application of filters. (And my +1 prior to the comment)